# How to access and use the data in JSON coming from google spreadsheet?

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs

My webapp needs a login authentication and we're using google spreadsheets to store user data
*unless you have a better solution, please do suggest*

I already have retrieved the spreadsheet data using [Tabletop](https://github.com/jsoma/tabletop)

[image: picture***]

and now from my username and password they need to match the ones that were retrieved.

The username and password is, of course user input.

I have tried this

```
{
    data.map(obj => {
        return (
            <div >
                <p >{obj.Passkey}</p>
            </div>
        )
    })
}
```

just to display the data in my webpage just to see if I can access the data but no luck.

This is what I've used to retrieve data from the spreadsheet

```
    componentDidMount() {
        Tabletop.init({
            key: '<spreadsheet key>',
            callback: (...googleData) => {
                const tabletop = googleData[1] // The tabletop object provided in callback
                const firstTab = tabletop.sheets('responses')
                console.log('googleData', firstTab)
                this.setState({ firstTab })
            }
        })
    }
```

its a login 
User inputs their data and that data needs to match the data coming from the spreadsheets

EDIT:

This is the whole code

```
class Login extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            data: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        Tabletop.init({
            key: '198WuzUQHEEzCSnDTHch-eQpBeW_7uHt14-LWvehbdE8',
            callback: (...googleData) => {
                const tabletop = googleData[1] // The tabletop object provided in callback
                const firstTab = tabletop.sheets('responses')
                // const secondTab = tabletop.sheets('[insert-tab-name-2]').all()
                console.log('googleData', firstTab)
                //this.setState({ firstTab })
                this.setState({
                    data: firstTab
                })
            }
        })
    }

    state = {
        passkeySaved: false //true
    }

    loadPasskey = () => {
        /* do something that will check user name and password
    then shift page to passkey */
    }

    render() {

        /*if this were true */
        /*  if ( this.state.passkeySaved ) {
              return <Redirect to='/passkey' />
          } */

        const { data } = this.state
        return (
            <div className="Login-container">
                {/* <!-- HEADER --> */}
                <div className="row Login-header">
                    <div className="col-12">
                        <img src={logo} />
                    </div>
                </div>
                {/* <!-- LOGIN FORM --> */}
                <div className="Login-textbox">
                    <div className="col-12">

                        <form method="post" className="gformLogin">
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <input type="email" className="form-control" id="userEmail" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Username" />
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <input type="password" className="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" aria-describedby="passwordHelp" placeholder="Password" />
                            </div>

                            <Link to="/passkey">
                                <button type="button" type="submit" value="submit" className="btn Login-btnPrimary" >LOGIN</button>
                            </Link>

                        </form>


                        {
                            data.map(obj => {

                                return (
                                    <div>
                                        <p>{obj[3]}</p>

                                    </div>
                                )

                            })
                        }



                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }

}

export default Login;
```

Comment: What is "data" over here ? I suppose its an array and not a JSON object.

Comment: Oh are these arrays? My mistake

Comment: Did the answer solve your question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who stumbles upon this question

I have it solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57300801/google-apps-script-wont-select-specific-sheet-in-spreadsheet)

goodluck

Answer (score 1):

From the example of data it looks like your `obj` inside the map is an array. So to print passkey try this.

```
data.map(obj => {
    return (
        <div >
            <p >{obj[2]}</p>
        </div>
    )
})
```

or if you index is anything else than 2 use it.

Comment: It doesnt seem to work

i've edited my question with the whole code for that page I am using rn

Comment: Ok so you are using react native. I think rn doesn't have div tag. Use View instead.

Comment: its because im using react js haha