# Google apps script wont select specific sheet in spreadsheet

Tags: reactjs, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I have multiple sheets in the spreadsheets and the code I have works only when the sheet is on first and but on other positions

```
var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var sheetName = '管理_201907_CUD';
var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(sheetName);
```

if i were to run the function solely it would work

```
function test(){

  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  .getSheetByName('管理_201907_CUD').getRange('A1')
  .setValue('test');

}
```

but then again the data i have is coming from a Reactjs web app using XHR
*it works but only when the sheet is on the first place and not on other positions*

Normally it should be `var sheetName = e.parameters.formGoogleSheetName;`

`e.parameters.formGoogleSheetName` takes it value from the web app but for now I directly inputted the sheetname

i just want my sheet to work even though its on a different place
from this

[image]

to this
[image]

Comment: Your first block of code doesn't work because `doc` (which is a Sheet, not a Spreadsheet) does not have the function `getSheetByName`.  Your `function test` is written correctly.  Does the first block of code contain a mistake?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your situation, when you are trying to use `var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();` by Web Apps, the sheet of 1st index is retrieved. And `getActiveSheet()` returns the sheet object. So when `doc.getSheetByName(sheetName)` is run, an error occurs. And when you request to Web Apps by `https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec?formGoogleSheetName=sheetName`, how about using `var sheetName = e.parameter.formGoogleSheetName` for retrieving the value? If this was not useful for your situation, I apologize.

Comment: @dwmorrin 
it works! Thank you so much i've deleted the `var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(sheetName);` and did this `    var sheetName = '管理_201907_CUD';
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);`

im gonna try it now getting data from the web app using this hope it works `var sheetName = e.parameters.formGoogleSheetName || "responses";`